# Can't stop BluetoothAdapter started from background service

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service which is running in background process.This service is going to search for bluetooth devices after the application is killed by user.

```
<service android:name=".BLEBackgroundService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":externalBLEProcess"/>
```

in BLEBacgroundService class I have:

```
public class BLEBackgroundService extends Service{
    .
    .
    .
    public BLEDetector bleDetector;

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        .
        .
        .
        Log.i(tag,"onStartCommand");            
        startScan();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    void startScan() {
        bleDetector.startScan();
        Log.d(tag,"StartScan");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        bleDetector.stopScan();
        Log.w(tag,"Service OnDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And in my BLEDetector class I have:

```
public class BLEDetector{
    .
    .
    .

    BluetoothAdapter mBAdapter;
    public void stopScan(){
        Log.i(tag,"StopScan");
        mBAdapter.stopLeScan(stopCallback);
    }
}
```

and in my activity here is how I start this service:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Intent serviceIntent;
    .
    .
    .
    //This part is inside a Retrofit Callback onResponse
    serviceIntent = new Intent(ItemListActivity.this,BLEBackgroundService.class);    

    serviceIntent.putExtra
    (BasicUtils.getStringResource(getApplicationContext()
    ,R.string.beaconJsonIdentifier),new Gson().toJson(beaconModel));

    serviceIntent.putExtra
    (BasicUtils.getStringResource
    (getApplicationContext(),R.string.currssiID), prgss);

    if (BleUtil.isBluetoothEnabled(getApplicationContext()))
                        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
    public void disableService(){
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
```

And when I try to stop this service I just call `disableService()`.
When I start service it calls `onCreate` successfully and service starts wroking on a seperate process which I can see logs from Logcat.But when I try to stop service it prints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after reading [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#ServiceLifecycle) part of document I realized that sometimes my services `onStartCommand` function is called twice (which I have no idea why) and since I created `bleDetector` every time `onStartCommand` function was being called, I lost reference to it.

So all I had to do was to check to see if `bleDetector` was null or not.

How ever I have no idea why `onStartCommand` is being called multiple times.I call `startService` just once in my activity when I get a successful response from server using retrofit.

**EDIT**:

Sometimes in my activity, `onResume` is called multiple times and that's the reason why my `startService` is called multiple times.